# How to Add ContextMenu Item to Mturk Requester

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, mturk

I'm writing a Chrome Extension and I need to add an item the context menu when right clicking a requester on the Mturk HIT Groups window. I've read how to add context menus but nothing seems to apply to adding an additional context item to an existing menu or how to connect that menu to my addition. Can someone point me to some documentation on how to accomplish that? TIA.

After a little more research I came up with this code:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: "autoselectid",
        title: "Auto Select",
        contexts: ["browser_action"],
        parentId: parentid
     });
```

This doesn't work as I get the error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot find menu item with id 2037286881
```

Since I can't find that error in my context, I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about MTurk but to add an new item to an already existing context menu you have to use **chrome.contextMenus.create** passing a new id and optionally the parentId as parameters (if that new item is nested inside another)

Comment: Thanks but that much I already know. It is getting the menu item into the correct context that I can't find the documentation for.

Comment: Let see us what you have already written so we can help you better.

Comment: I added my code to the OP.

Comment: Try to remove the whole menu object and recreate it anytime you need in this way:
  chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(_ => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(menu_1);
    chrome.contextMenus.create(menu_2);
});

Comment: But there are other menu items that are not associated with my extension.

Comment: What do you mean? From your extension you can't modify any other menus other than your menus.  Menus are normally created (after preventive destruction) in the onInstall event handler.  
These menus remain persistent until the next extension update (unless they are voluntarily destroyed first by hand).
The typical errors encountered when working with menus is that an item with a particular id already exists.
Try to create a minimal extension that recreates the problem you are facing and share with us.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).